# How can spacecraft manufactured on the moon be powered?

Tags: technology, hard-science, moons, space-colonization, power-sources

**Background:**
The moon has been selected as the base for human space exploration. Rather than ship tonnes of material out of earth's gravity well, interplanetary spacecraft and space stations will be manufactured on the surface of the moon and launched from there.

A level of industrial capacity allowing the mining and processing of ores has been developed on the moon, as well as manufacturing, and reasonably good material science using moon resources. As a rough guideline, if a material could have been manufactured on earth in the 1970s a reasonable substitute in terms of material properties can now be manufactured on the moon. If you can justify why a material exceeding that standard can be manufactured on the moon, you can use it.

*Note:* To clarify, the tech level does not need to be restricted to the 1970s (the target is in the future but with minimal additional scientific advances). I have placed this restriction on the level of material science because developing simple structural materials (e.g. steel) on the moon would pose significant challenges, but the details are beyond the scope of the question.

**The question:**
How will these spacecraft manufactured on the moon be powered?

**Criteria:**

- The more realistic the power source is based on current science the better: Currently implemented > Prototyped > In development > theoretical > hypothetical > impossible
- The raw materials should be found on the moon, with as little mass as possible imported from earth. The more abundant and easily processed the raw materials are the better.
- The answer should explain how the power source is able to power both the craft's propulsion and its other power requirements.
- The end result must be a portable power source for the spacecraft, with both the drive for the spacecraft and any fuels required manufactured and produced on the moon. The same levels of credibility apply to the drive as to the power source.

*Note:* 
I am looking for the craft's principal power source. Because some power sources lend themselves more easily to providing propulsion I feel an explanation of the propulsion system used in conjunction with the power source is also necessary.

**Examples of power sources**

- moon manufactured solar panels with batteries, and an electrically powered propulsion system.
- hydrogen, oxygen, and rocket engines manufactured on the moon.
- space ready nuclear-powered engine made on the moon

**Excellent answers will provide** evidence for how well developed the power source currently is. Evidence for how well-developed drives which can work with that power source are. Evidence for ores of any crucial raw materials on the moon.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86036/discussion-on-question-by-ben-how-can-spacecraft-manufactured-on-the-moon-be-pow).

Comment: One propellant combination that can be sourced from the moon is powdered aluminum and oxygen. For background, see the following NASA Technical Memo: [https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19940017287.pdf](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19940017287.pdf)

Comment: As the OP I would prefer the question to remain hard science. The best answers on this question I feel meet that standard - with links to credible sources for all major points. As the person asking the question I am biased towards liking answers even if they don't meet the hard science standard - but I think that hard-science  is the most appropriate standard for the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An Aluminium-Oxygen drive burns Aluminium and Oxygen (as the name would suggest), achieving a mediocre [specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse) (the primary measure of fuel efficiency for rockets) of about [285 seconds](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/enginelist.php#al02rocket).  Normally this would be of no interest for use as a rocket fuel since current Hydrogen-Oxygen drives such as those used for the Space Shuttle's main engines can achieve specific impulses of around [450 seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_main_engine), far superior to the pathetic specific impulse provided by Aluminium-Oxygen combustion.

However, the advantage of an Aluminium-Oxygen engine is the fact that you can make the fuel out of nothing more than regolith (lunar dirt and rock) and electricity.  According to [this paper](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/isijinternational/56/7/56_ISIJINT-2016-037/_pdf), reducing Aluminium Oxide, which is [present in the lunar regolith](https://isru.nasa.gov/MetalsfromRegolith.html), requires high temperatures (above 1832 K), which can be provided by solar power, as well as [Carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geology_of_the_Moon#Elemental_composition) and [Iron Oxide](https://isru.nasa.gov/MetalsfromRegolith.html), both of which are available in the lunar regolith (although getting enough Carbon will require processing a lot of ore, and it would be reclaimed from the CO2 after the reaction to as great an extent as possible).  This reduction was performed for the linked paper above, so it's clearly in the "Already Implemented" stage.

Actually building a rocket that uses Aluminium and Oxygen as fuel will be fairly simple, as it's essentially just a fairly inefficient [hybrid-propellant rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid-propellant_rocket), which is a type of rocket we've already built and flown a number of, and are easily capable of building more of if the need should arise (the need hasn't arisen because liquid fuels have higher specific impulses, but the various liquid fuels in use on Earth are much harder to produce on the moon, so using Aluminium and Oxygen is a viable alternative).  So this is somewhere between the "Prototyped" stage (as we don't have an Aluminium Oxygen drive specifically yet) and the "Currently Implemented" (because we do have many hybrid rockets of other types) stage.

Therefore, spacecraft manufactured on the moon could be propelled by an Aluminium-Oxygen drive, using propellant manufactured on the moon with nothing but lunar dirt, a solar farm, and some already-built equipment.

Comment: That's probably best system for just ferrying stuff to lunar orbit

Comment: @Mranderson I must admit that it's abysmal specific impulse does make it unsuited to longer missions, yes.  The higher stages of long missions (anything interplanetary, with the possible exception of Mars) would likely be better serviced by something like H2/LOX rockets with fuel made from lunar ice (see ShadoCat's answer).

Comment: How would this compare to using hydrogen peroxide, if there was a lot of water ice available?

Comment: @Innovine as stated in the answer, the specific impulse of this kind of drive is abysmal compared to every variety of rocket currently in use.  The abundance of fuel, no matter where on the lunar surface you go, is the main benefit.  There is water ice available on the moon, but it is nearly entirely present at the poles, the worst possible location to launch a rocket from.  Additionally, there are significant problems with fuel storage and reliability for hydrogen peroxide drives (they like to blow up) that make hydrogen-oxygen fuels far superior in the vast majority of situations.

Comment: Interesting, because when I asked a separate question about that, I was informed that h2o2 was a much better fuel due to issues in storing high pressure hydrogen.

Comment: @Innovine the main issue with H2O2 is that it likes to slowly decompose to H2O and O2.  This increases tank pressure (eventually leading to an explosion), and also releases heat.  Heat increases the rate of decomposition of the other H2O2 in the tank, which releases more heat, which causes more H2O2 to decompose even faster, and eventually either your tank explodes (if it isn't properly vented), or your rocket fuel ends up turning into water and oxygen, which are rather useless for propelling rockets.  For more information, you can check out the amazing book "Ignition" by John D. Clark.

Comment: For chemical fuels, how about Hydrogen-Fluorine mix? Highly reactive, although toxic and corrosive. It would certainly never be allowed on Earth but perhaps the Moon would be a perfect test station?

Comment: @Lelu Neither of those elements is exactly plentiful in regolith, and Flourine is extremely dangerous.  I'd recommend staying away from it if you enjoy not being on fire.

Comment: @Gryphon Hydrogen is available in the solar wind being blown onto the Moon, right? Also I know that fluorine is dangerous, but this is why we test it only outside of Earth, no?

Answer (score 11):

A brute force concept using [1970s technology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000GRMI7K) and lunar materials:

Use lunar ores to make reflective materials and [Stirling engines](https://www.infogalactic.com/info/Stirling_engine).  Use these materials to build [solar-thermal power plants](https://www.infogalactic.com/info/List_of_solar_thermal_power_stations) on the moon.  Store the energy using [molten-metal batteries](https://news.mit.edu/2016/battery-molten-metals-0112) or batteries that [melt-and-refreeze metals or salts](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.rser.2012.10.022), also made using lunar material.

Use high-power ablation technology for the rockets.  The bottom of the ship is a large shaped piece of metal.  Send an intense energy beam from the launch site to the bottom of the ship.  Boil off the metal, to provide thrust.  Earth-based launchers using this concept would need about 3 GW of power.  (Per "[Halfway to Anywhere](https://www.baen.com/readonline/index/read/sku/0491029411)", in *[A Step Farther Out](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000GRMI7K)*.)  Since the moon has about 1/6 of Earth's gravity, 500 MW would suffice.

Bonus points if the "intense energy beam" is a laser beam, mounted on a stuffed shark.  (The sharkskin would probably need to be imported from Earth.)

Include a small-scale solar-thermal system on the spaceship, along with a small-scale version of the battery system.  Send a modest energy beam from the moon to the ship's solar-thermal system to power the spaceship.

Comment: Do you have any references for the availability of suitable ores for molten metal batteries on the moon?

Comment: The molten-metal battery concept is very flexible.  A wide range of metals are suitable.  The original concept was to use aluminum.  Aluminum is an element in much of the moon's rocks.

Comment: @Ben - Another concept that could be called a "molten metal battery" is to melt a metal with a low melting point (such as sodium or aluminum) to store energy, and let it re-freeze to release energy.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geology_of_the_Moon for elements

Comment: This is not a hard science answer. Add more technical evidence that this system will work.

Comment: Minor nitpick, but according to the excellent [Atomic Rockets](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/enginelist.php#ablativelaser) site, the optimum material for an ablative laser drive (which is what this is) is graphite, rather than a metal.  Metal would work, but wouldn't achieve as high a specific impulse.

Comment: @Gryphon -- Thank you for the link.  Artemijs' link shows that, given enough energy, we can refine Lunar surface rocks to get metals.  Graphite is not nearly as abundant on the moon.  Your link suggests that Magnesium might be a better choice than iron.  Also, 4,000 seconds of specific impulse for graphite is awesome; we can afford to do significantly worse.

Comment: @Jasper while we can afford to do worse than 4,000 seconds (heck, my answer suggests Al-O2 with a measly 285 seconds), we don't want to if we don't have to.  Still, your point about the rarity of carbon on the lunar surface is a good one, and you're correct that a metal is a more likely candidate for a realistic drive.

Answer (score 6):

"The Japanese Kaguya spacecraft, which was launched in 2007, detected uranium with a gamma-ray spectrometer. Scientists are using the instrument to create maps of the moon's surface composition, showing the presence of thorium, potassium, oxygen, magnesium, silicon, calcium, titanium and iron."

https://www.space.com/6904-uranium-moon.html

Thus the obvious solution is to build a nuclear fission reactor on the moon and build a uranium mine.  Nuclear fission (and fusion) do not require oxygen, so no atmosphere is needed on the moon.

[Nuclear thermal rockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_thermal_rocket) were prototyped and had (non-flight) tests from the 1950s to 1970s.

> To date, no nuclear thermal rocket has flown, although the NERVA
>   NRX/EST and NRX/XE were built and tested with flight design
>   components. The highly successful U.S. Project Rover which ran from
>   1955 through 1972 accumulated over 17 hours of run time. The NERVA
>   NRX/XE, judged by SNPO to be the last "technology development" reactor
>   necessary before proceeding to flight prototypes, accumulated over 2
>   hours of run time, including 28 minutes at full power. The Russian
>   nuclear thermal rocket RD-0410 was also claimed by the Soviets to have
>   gone through a series of tests at the nuclear test site near
>   Semipalatinsk.

Comment: This seems like a good start to an answer, but how can this be used to power spacecraft launched from the moon?

Comment: @Ben: in [very terrifying way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NERVA) I'd guess.

Comment: Or an [even more terrifying way.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_\(nuclear_propulsion\))

Comment: @Ben Also, as per your metrics, this answer would be at the "prototyped" level. Nuclear rockets were built decades ago and were tested  and shown to work but never put to use for various reasons.

Comment: @Ben Deleted my previous question and just edited a Wikipedia link and quote into hyperion's answer. Basically just heat a gas up really hot and fling it out the back at high speed. Heating things up is something nuclear fission reactions are good at.

Comment: This is a nice answer. Unfortunately it seems like these uranium supplies are unlikely to be in high enough concentration to be usable https://www.space.com/8644-moon-map-shows-uranium-short-supply.html

Comment: This is not a hard science answer. Where are these deposits? Are they economically retrievable? What is the list of components that a nuclear thermal rocket uses? Can you launch one without irradiating the environment?

Comment: I'd also like to note that this is not a drive I want to be anywhere near the launch point of.  Accidents in this kind of rocket tend to be rather catastrophic.

Comment: Less catastrophic than Chernobyl-style accidents or NTR accidents on Earth, because fallout wouldn't be carried by air for example, just fall in few specific places. Depending on failure mode, the reactor might just fall in one spot, generating not much of a problem. The worst would probably be the reactor disintegrating in flight, which would throw material out of reactor far away from the accident position.

Comment: Nuclear Power Plants need water. Water is rare on the moon and will have other uses beyond be boiled in reactors

Comment: Will fission power production work on the moon? There is a LOT of waste heat from the process. On earth this gives rise to the typical cooling towers, and plants often being sited along the seafront or waterways, as they are used as heatsinks. I think maybe there will be major problems disposing of waste heat in a lunar vacuum

Comment: @kingledion “Irradiating the environment” isn’t a problem. You’re on the Moon, and a bit of stray radio isotope will not make it significantly more uninhabitable than it already is.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest method of obtaining a rocket fuel from the Moon is to mine the ice on the poles.  This gives rocket fuel from a single mining source.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_water):

> In March 2010, it was reported that the Mini-SAR on board
>   Chandrayaan-1 had discovered more than 40 permanently darkened craters
>   near the Moon's north pole that are hypothesized to contain an
>   estimated 600 million metric tonnes (1.3 trillion pounds) of
>   water-ice.

Then you just need a bit of heat, a lot of electricity and the ability to compress and to separately store H2 and O2.

You melt the water and use Electrolysis to split the water.*

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis_of_water) link for if you don't know what that is:

> This technique can be used to make hydrogen gas and breathable oxygen.
>   As hydrogen is an important industrial commodity, by far most
>   industrial methods produce hydrogen from natural gas instead, in the
>   steam reforming process.

Then you just use cryogenic compression to convert the gases to liquid form for storage.

If the ice is not where you want to be launching rockets from, it is easy to transport the ice to the launch area.  I would recommend that over transporting the O2 and H2 gases.  For one thing, if the transport breaks down, ice will evaporate much more slowly than cryogenic liquid gasses.

*When did they change the term from cracking water to splitting water?  A search on "crack water" yielded a whole bunch of links that I wasn't looking for.

Comment: Although water ice is a good solution, it has a number of annoying properties, including only being found at the poles, which are the worst place to launch from and land on, meaning you have to either haul ice to the lunar equator or launch ships into polar orbits.  Another annoying thing is that its only found in permanently shadowed places, where you can't get solar power to crack the ice, so you have to haul it out of the crater first, and even then the solar power at the poles is far lower than that at the equator, so it takes a long time to split the fuel.

Comment: @Gryphon, that is why I talked about transporting the ice.  Also, the poles might be the best place to generate electricity.  Just as there are craters that have permanent shadows, there are peaks that have close to continual sunlight.  That would allow splitting almost year round.

Comment: There's also the issue that the ice (at least the ice observed so far) is at a rather low concentration.  You'd need some substantial refinement before you even start splitting the water.

Comment: Another issue is that water on the moon seems likely to be a highly valuable resource in such a scenario - so using it as rocket fuel might not be economical.

Comment: @Ben with 600 million tonnes of it, it's not like there isn't enough to go around.  If my math is right, that's enough to launch a Space Shuttle every day for several millennia.  Of course, the extraction rate does have to be taken into account, but on sheer quantity available, we wouldn't run out anytime soon (if you accept the 600 million tonne estimate, but I doubt it's off by more than an order of magnitude or so).

Comment: @Ben, launching from the Moon is a springboard to mining ice from the asteroids.  Once we get there, we can pay the Moon back with interest.

Comment: @Gryphon, yes they'd have to process a lot of rock but the refinement process is as simple as running it through a transparent tube with a parabolic mirror focused on it to melt or vaporize the ice.  A condenser coil stuck into the tube (out of range of the heat), would then form a cylinder of ice which could be recovered into a sealed container.  No need for pressure, just sunlight and a conveyor belt.

Comment: @ShadoCat that's true, but it does mean that more energy is required to boil off the ice, and more regolith needs to be mined and processed.  It's not a show-stopper, but it reduces the efficiency and speed of production.

Comment: @Gryphon, Speed maybe but with the mirror, the boiling is, essentially, free.  After the start up costs, running the whole processing plant will just involve shoving in ore and removing dry ore and ice cylinders.  That should provide a slow steady supply of fuel to go find a good ice asteroid.  I see it as the most economical way to jump start asteroid mining.

Comment: @ShadoCat it's mostly the fact that you're going to need to process a *lot* of regolith.  Over a thousand tonnes of it per tonne of ice, if [this](https://phys.org/news/2017-09-global-moon-soil.html) source is correct. Asteroid belt missions are going to require thousands, if not tens of thousands of tonnes of fuel, so that's a whole lot of regolith to process. If your solar water extractor can process a kilogram of ore a second, it's going to take over eleven and a half days per tonne of fuel produced, assuming you can keep it running constantly.

Comment: @Gryphon, maybe combine my idea with Ben's below.  Use the hydrogen for the heavy lifting and the ion engine to get to the belt.

Comment: @ShadoCat that might work, if there's enough easily-ionized propellent on the moon.  Sorry if it seems I'm being excessively critical, I'm just trying to figure out potential problems.  I can get overly nitpicky sometimes, so yeah, sorry about that.

Comment: @Gryphon, NP. I am not an expert on any of this.  I am not a scientist.  My expertise is business and economics.  Your criticisms have let me to think about some things that hadn't occurred to me.

Answer (score 4):

**Solar power combined with ion engines and a mass driver:**

**Power Source**

Solar power could conceivably be used to power the craft, providing both the onboard power and propulsion.

Solar power is already widely implemented, with solar panels [sufficient to supply 227 Gigawatts](https://www.worldenergy.org/data/resources/resource/solar/) of electricity having been installed globally by 2015.

The main component of most photovoltaic cells [is silicon](https://news.energysage.com/what-are-solar-panels-made-of-list-of-solar-pv-materials/). This is the second most abundant element on the lunar surface, however, it exists in various ores rather than the relatively pure form used for solar panels on earth. A process to extract silicon from these ores would be required. Such a process [has been suggested](http://www.asi.org/adb/02/13/02/silicon-production.html).

**Propulsion in space**

For propulsion while in space solar panels could be combined with ion drives - this is a technology which [has already been implemented](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/glenn/about/fs21grc.html). Ion drives require a propellant, for this a range of elements have been used or proposed, including xenon, argon, iodine, mercury, and bismuth. Designs such as [VASMIR](http://www.adastrarocket.com/aarc/VASIMR) could theoretically use practically any material for propellant. Thus it should be possible to find a suitable propellant on the moon.

**Propulsion to launch**

Ion drives do not, however, provide sufficient thrust to escape lunar gravity. This could be achieved by accelerating the craft on a track using linear motors, as implemented in maglev trains on earth. There are many implementations for transportation on earth, but so far this has not been used to propel a vehicle to lunar escape velocity. Such a launch system [has been proposed](https://phys.org/news/2012-03-maglev-track-spacecraft-orbit.html) for use on earth, where air resistance and a much higher escape velocity pose challenges not encountered on the moon.

**Summary**

Solar panels could be used to power propulsion systems which can be run on electricity. Ion drives provide such a propulsion system for use in space, and mass drivers provide such a system for launch.

Comment: Other points which would improve this answer, but which I haven't got round to include: info on the feasibility of manufacturing batteries on the moon, and info on the elements required to build an ion engine. Also, are there any usable sources of xenon, argon, iodine, mercury or bismuth on the moon?

Comment: Exactly. Why bother with expensive chemical propellants when you can just build a space catapult to launch a ion-driven spaceship directly into orbit? However, the catapult still needs to be quite big, as you need to accelerate to more than 6000km/h, and the ion drive needs to be powerful enough to raise the pericenter of the orbit out of the danger zone within the first two hours of flight. The higher the end speed from the catapult, the more time the ion drive has to do its work.

Answer (score 1):

**Magnetic propulsion.  For 6 days every month.**

[image: earth's magnetic tail]

https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/222898main_orbit2_20080416_HI.jpg

The moon moves through the Earth's magnetic field in the course of its orbit.  Once in the field, moon-based spacecraft could move via electromagnetic propulsion.  This is not science fiction.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrodynamic_tether

> Electrodynamic tethers (EDTs) are long conducting wires, such as one
>   deployed from a tether satellite, which can operate on electromagnetic
>   principles as generators, by converting their kinetic energy to
>   electrical energy, or as motors, converting electrical energy to
>   kinetic energy.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fi2V.jpg) Electric potential is generated across a conductive
>   tether by its motion through a planet's magnetic field.

Spacecraft with batteries (charged by solar panels during the other 24 days of the month) charge up their long tethers and use them to propel themselves about, pushing against the Earths field during its monthly visit.

Longer and more energetic tethers might be used all month long, pushing against the relatively weaker electromagnetic field of the sun and the charged particles of the solar wind.

Comment: While this is an interesting idea for maneuvering in space, I'm fairly sure that it will not provide enough thrust to lift off from the lunar surface (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).  What mechanism would you propose for achieving orbit in the first place?

Comment: Electrostatic propulsion is something different, but it is apparently enough for dust to lift off the surface of the moon and scoot around.  https://www.space.com/35240-moon-dust-levitates-nasa-study.html   So to lift off - electrostatic repulsion from the moon.  For flying around: electrodynamic propulsion.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend two books that came out in the '70s

G. Harry Stine "The Third Industrial Revolution"

and

Heppenheimer's "Colonies in Space"

I see both in used book stores on a regular basis.

Stines notions was that you build orbital power satellites that would beam microwave energy down to receiving antenna on Earth.  You use phased array to keep the beam narrow.  No, the energy isn't enough to cook you if you are on the receiving antenna.

Material is mined on the moon and launched to a Lagrange point by a rail gun.  There it is broken down using kilometer diameter solar mirrors.  Much of the waste is silica -- which can be foamed and used as structural infill.  Aluminum is the main structural material.  Some silica is broken down to silicon (solar cells) and Oxygen (breathing)  Hydrogen is in short supply.  But if you can make oxygen, then you only have to ship up 1/8 the amount of rocket fuel you did before.  And maybe those polar craters on the moon *do* have water in them.

Stine is convincing.  He has an engineering background and had access to various think tank reports from the likes of the Rand Corporation.

Colonies in space is a bit further out and is more about establishing more than a work camp in zero-G.

Iron seems to be in short supply on the moon.  H. proposes a nuclear rocket.   Build a nuclear reactor that gets hot enough to turn gravel into hot gas.  You can move asteroids then by landing such a rocket and a gravel crusher.  At this point, I don't think we can make a nuclear engine that directly operates at those temperatures.  Make electricity, make a plasma.  Electrically accelerate the plasma.  You can get huge specific impulse this way.  It's not hard to get plasma up to a respectable fraction of light speed.  It's more efficient however to accelerate more mass to a lower speed.

Be sure of your trajectories.  Don't want to drop a 3-mile rock on the Earth by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest propellant to make on the moon would be ALICE,  or an aluminum nano-power mixed with ice.  No need to separate out the oxygen and hydrogen from the water.

[ALICE Rocket Fuel Tests](https://web.archive.org/web/20091007101459/http://pdf.aiaa.org/preview/CDReadyMJPC09_1980/PV2009_4877.pdf)

Another option is to use pure water heated with a nuclear reactor, making a steam rocket.  This does not have the specific impulse of hydrogen/oxygen, meaning that it does not provide as much momentum change per unit mass of propellant,  but it has a number of large advantages: You don't have to worry about handling cryogenic fuels,  the spacecraft is simpler,  the fuel tank can just be a bladder, etc.

[Steam Rocket Powered by Lunar Water](https://web.archive.org/web/20211102172844/http://www.neofuel.com/moonicerocket/)

Answer (score 0):

Sodium in nuclear thermal rockets,  or the same sodium as remass in an aluminium oxygen hybrid rocket.

Sodium with an atomic mass of 23, is surprisingly good as an NTR propellant. Working near the melting point of uranium dioxide, the said propellant produced just over 300 seconds of ISP. Equivalent to that of modern storable propellants in term of specific impulse.

If combined with a graphite moderator, the ISP reaches 340 to 350s， high enough for most transfers, and certainly enough to reach nearby planets.

The sodium can be obtained as a byproduct from processing lunar feldspar rocks for aluminum construction material and breathing oxygen.

Sodium in a reaction of aluminum and oxygen greatly increases the thermal property of the plume and produces an ISP rating about 360 to 370s. This is viable for a Jupiter transfer.

Also, you can harvest lithium from lunar rocks and burn it in liquid oxygen. This affords more than 550 seconds of ISP,  which is enough to send an interplanetary invasion. Lithium is also good for propellant of (artillery) guns, and as an energetic material in explosives.

Lastly, sodium and lithium can be used as a propellant for electric drives, which can be powered by silicon solar panels manufacturable from moon rocks. Or a fission reactor has to be shipped from the earth.

However, sending just the uranium 233 will not be too expensive, at least not as expensive as sending all the propellants up to the moon. This makes the whole fuel production process economically viable.

There is thorium ore on the moon, so nuclear power will be the go. Build the reactor on the moon, and you will be able to sell space service even back to the earth!

In summary, use alkaline metals to replace the hydrogen, and it shouldn't be too hard to build spaceships on the moon.

Comment: The question has the hard science tag, meaning that answers should be backed up by citations. Can you provide such?

Comment: all the energy / specific impulse profiles specified above is calculated with Children of a Dead Earth , the most realistic space battle simulator, using real world enthalpy of formation/standard entropy data. The cost of the elements/materials are calculated using real world data on lunar soil / solar abundance of the elements. Power generation and refining is assumed to happen on the surface and is therefore irrelevant for this calculation.

Answer (score -1):

While not really a propellant, since we as a civilization started to explore the seas using sails, there's no reason why we wouldn't (at least at first) explore space in a similar fashion.

Enter Solar Sails:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail

Another idea would be to turn the moon in a 'laser beam hedgehog' and use powerful lasers to propel spaceships across our solar system, in a similar fashion to a solar sail.

Otherwise, at current, the best conventional engine is still the Hydrogen Engine: https://www.nasa.gov/topics/technology/hydrogen/hydrogen_fuel_of_choice.html 
It (liquid hydrogen), however, would have to be obtained from water from ice mined from the asteroid belt and shipped to the moon.

Comment: I like the idea of using resources from elsewhere in the solar system. Though not strictly to the letter of the question, it gets the spirit of it. How would the lasers be powered?

Comment: @Ben and answerer: Do note that unlike sailboats (per the analogy), a solar sail driven craft can accelerate only away from the light source. That means a solar sail spacecraft is more limited than a sailboat. A sailboat can, contrary to common sense, sail against the wind - though only at an angle against the wind up to approximately 45 degrees away from the wind, not directly into the wind at 0 degrees from it. This is not an all-stop roadblock and it could still be useful, but it does need to be part of all planning (ie: How are we going to stop when we arrive?)

Comment: Solar sails have a thrust-to-weight ratio far less than 1.  Once you get them into orbit, sure, you've got a fuel-free way to go anywhere.  But what are you going to use to launch them?

Comment: How do you take off from the surface of the planet with a solar sail? This is not a hard-science answer, add more technical evidence that your plan is feasible.

Comment: @Aaron, although one can't directly thrust towards the light source, one can "tack" to slow down one's orbit and allow the gravity of the light source to pull one in.

Comment: @Loduwijk: reflective solar sails produce thrust normal to the sail, and can angle the sail to "tack".

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff That does not explain how one would go in the opposite direction as the light. Sailing ships can turn partially into the wind because of the keel on the water. If spacecraft had something in space to react against in the same way, then sure, but we don't. How are you going to tack **toward** the light source? The best you can do is to use it to accelerate you at a nearly, but just barely less than, 90 degree angle from the light source but still pushing away, not toward, the light. Unless I'm missing something, which would be great.

Comment: For solar sailing in solar orbit, the sun both emits light and has gravity. Angle your sail to reduce your orbital velocity and you move toward the sun. For beam sailing, about half your interactions with a beam station will involve a trajectory roughly approaching it, and angling the sail can trivially bend such a trajectory closer to the beam station. Apart from that, again you can angle your sail to adjust your orbit around whatever the beam station is orbiting or on the surface of however you wish, including raising or lowering your orbit to approach closer to the beam station.

Answer (score -1):

Straying slightly from currently available technologies to those that are possible, but not yet achieved...

The Lunar surface is rich in Helium-3, so if Helium-3 fusion propulsion is developed, there is abundant fuel for it.

https://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Preparing_for_the_Future/Space_for_Earth/Energy/Helium-3_mining_on_the_lunar_surface

Comment: The top few centimeters of the lunar surface contain low-double-digit parts per billion of helium-3. Also, you can get all the benefits of He-3 fusion with p/B-11 fusion, without having to burn a fuel that requires you to scrape up and process billions of tons of lunar regolith.

Answer (score -1):

In all honestly, although there are many *feasible* answers, there is only one true *correct* answer.

Tritium

Tritium is one of the best fuel sources in the solar system, by a wide margin. Uranium radioactive and requires massive infrastructure to run. Hydrocarbons have annoying side effects and are some of the least efficient fuel sources for effort put in, and solar takes a lot of work just to get a small amount (of albeit non-fueled) energy.

Tritium is fairly safe as far as fuels go and constantly being spewed off by the sun in massive amounts. It's energy dense, and can largely be 'burned' as is (resulting in hydrogen which... can just be burned again). However, it reacts with Earth's atmosphere, rendering it into old fashioned H2 (aka, hydrogen), so on the surface of Earth, Tritium is useless, and is worth *significantly* more than it's weight in gold and never gets used as a fuel source.

The moon, however, is a Tritium sponge. In a day's worth of a single person harvesting, they could harvest enough Tritium to pay for the trip to the moon. In a year, it could cover our entire world's space program to date. And this is before you get serious tritium sifting infrastructure going.

It's such a ridiculous gold-rush like opportunity, that every multi-million dollar corporation that's *not* trying to go to the moon is stupid.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the reason for the high price of tritium is its rarity.  Were a company to go to the moon and bring back tonnes of the stuff, it's price would plunge, and the load would be worth a few dollars a gram, at the most.  The Apollo program and its precursor Gemini cost a total of 288 billion in 2019 dollars.  Even assuming we manage to cut that cost a hundredfold for a second set of lunar missions, there's no way it would be able to pay for itself by shipping back tritium.

Comment: Just a bit of a nitpick on your statement that "every multi-million dollar corporation that's *not* trying to go to the moon is stupid".  Sorry if it turned into a bit of a rant.

Comment: @Gryphon It's actually in the same boat as Aluminium. Back in the early days of the US, Aluminium couldn't be manufactured, you could only get lucky and mine it pure. It was literally worth more than it's weight in gold, and was considered one of the most valuable minerals on the planet (which made it a big deal they capped the Washington Monument with it). Then cheap aluminium production was invented, and the price of Aluminium PER POUND plummeted, yes, but the value of the Aluminium INDUSTRY skyrocketed. The reason is because a regularly used substance is a more value industry than rarity.

Comment: @Gryphon and as an industry grows with an initially-rare resource, the profit-margins are insane, especially the more useful it is. And since tritium is the best fuel, and has other uses, it falls in that category more solidly than anything in history. Demand would outpace production increases. With the extraction method literally involving heading to another world, that means that profit margin AND low competition, which means the profit-margins would make simple rarity commodities seem like a joke.

Comment: @Gryphon And to top it off, it would be an energy/fuel industry, giving it the demand increase projection of oil. In short, the first company that CAN make Tritium Moon Mining a thing will be THE most wealthy business in the world, within a decade, hands down, no contest. It's a perfect storm of economic opportunity.

Comment: @Gryphon and considering Tritium is energy-dense enough to put conventional rocket fuels to shame, it would not only make that company super rich terrestrially, but as the saying goes, "In a gold rush, don't hunt for gold, sell the pickaxes." They would be selling the pickaxes of a new space age gold rush that would be emerging that supplied things like this little gem: https://www.foxnews.com/science/nasa-headed-towards-giant-golden-asteroid-that-could-make-everyone-on-earth-a-billionaire

Comment: A couple of points: The reason the value of the Aluminium industry skyrocketed was that, as you say "cheap aluminium production was invented."  Emphasis on the word "cheap".  Say we mount a second set of moon missions.  Say we, by some miracle of engineering, manage to drop the price 100-fold from the first time.  That means it costs about 29 billion dollars.  Say we also manage to optimize more for retrieving lunar samples, bringing back twice as much as we did then, somehow also bringing along equipment to refine the tritium so we're bringing it back pure, all at 1/100 the original cost.

Comment: The first time around, we brought back 842 lb. of moon stuff.  We doubled that somehow, so we bring back 1,684 lb.  The current price of tritium is about 15 million per pound.  This gives us a total revenue from selling our 1,684 lb. of tritium of 25.26 billion.  Which means our total profit is -3.74 billion dollars.  And this is a scenario in which we have a magically cheap launch, carry along tritium refining equipment at no extra cost, and bring back twice as much stuff as we did the first time.  I'm pretty sure that lunar tritium mining is not going to be profitable in the near future.

Comment: Additionally, this is assuming that we somehow kept the price of Tritium stable, despite dumping 1,684 lb of a material that usually has a production of about 2 grams per year onto the open market.  If tritium was a viable substance to produce at the price lunar mining requires, we would be making tons of it, because we can already make it cheaper on earth.

Comment: @Gryphon
First off, a SpaceX Falcon heavy, which has the requisite power for a lunar mission, only costs 90 million. A Lunar-based Space-Elevator is buildable with current tech, which the LiftPort space group estimates about 100 million which covers lunar landing, retrieval, and return to the orbiting heavy. The mining equipment is a simple scoop and filter bot, you're looking at 100k (you just have to patient for it to do it's thing.) You're looking at a full reusable setup running 200.2M, NOT 29 Billion. You're off by two orders of magnitude, with the second trip becoming effectively free.

Comment: @Gryphon Because the Falcon Heavy is reusable, so is the space elevator, and the bot can keep digging and sifting while you're away, and the Falcon Heavy can be refueled and retooled to use a portion of the Tritium mined (reducing its launch cost in fuel significantly, allowing a MUCH larger payload), meaning the effectively free second launch can carry MUCH more mining equipment. First two or three trips, the Tritium could, with proper economic management, be sold off at full cost with much more than quintuple capacity cargo on return.  You're looking at nearly $500 Billion in pure profit

Comment: @Gryphon And that's just in the first 3 missions. In a year, said company could easily be in the Trillions of pure profit. Within a decade, said company could easily be the first company to break the 10 Trillion dollar mark.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99317/discussion-between-gryphon-and-liljoshu).

Comment: ...tritium is not produced by the sun and is not available in any notable quantity on the moon. Its properties are also nothing at all as described: it burns in oxygen to form tritium water, from which it can be extracted again just like normal hydrogen. It's not especially safe, being a radioactive isotope of hydrogen which will happily take the place of hydrogen in the body. It is primarily useful for two things: you can fuse it with deuterium in one of the more practical fusion reactions to produce power, or you can let it decay into helium-3, which has numerous scientific applications.

Comment: Fair. Although they're not the same thing by any stretch, since tritium naturally decays into helium-3, I often make the mistake of using them interchangeably, and that's nobody's fault other than my own brain's laziness (adding He3's properties to Tritium's) To be fair, He3 that's more dominant on the moon than Tritium, meaning it can be mined there as well. However, stars, including our sun, do make Tritium in their core, which is then later emitted, and the Moon is a decent 'sponge' that catches it.

Comment: The conditions in stellar cores burn any tritium in fusion reactions faster than it can be produced. Even the heavier brown dwarfs consume all their deuterium and lithium in more difficult reactions. As for He-3, it is completely unreactive with Earth's atmosphere, can not be burned to produce hydrogen, is only potentially useful as a power source in much more difficult fusion reactions than those being pursued today (which would not be very useful for getting rockets off the moon), and there's only around 10-20 parts per billion in lunar regolith, and that only in the top couple centimeters.

Comment: The only real difficulty with He-3 as a fusion reaction is that it runs hotter than other fusion reactions, a tempature which not only can it's energy output can maintain, but the tritium that decays into it can be used to kickstart the process. Further, since it doesn't create radioactivity, meaning it's much more feasible for more naked reactors, allowing weight reduction on final implementation. Further, even if twas merely a 10 parts per billion in the top few centimeters (debatable, what I've seen in papers indicates -much- higher abundance), it's still orders of magnitude more than Earth

Comment: Not to mention mining on the moon is insanely simpler than Earth. Unlike Earth which has had weather pounding down on it forever, the moon doesn't have an atmosophere. On the moon, it's a simple matter of scoop and spin, and picking out the elements you want. Not to mention He3 is only one of the most valuable of these. Pretty much the entirety of regolith is non-oxidized minerals ready and waiting for separation and converting to industrial process.

Comment: Tritium is no more useful for "kickstarting" He-3 fusion than any other source of energy for starting up a fusion reactor, and He-3 fusion isn't the only aneutronic reaction: p-B11 fusion is aneutronic and doesn't rely on scarce fuels. As for mining, on Earth concentration by weathering is the reason many ore deposits exist. On the moon, not only are the minerals mostly just as oxidized as they are on Earth, in the regolith they're all mixed up and you're likely to have to resort to high-energy processes like molten oxide electrolysis to separate them.